# How to use hashed values as an Index in Python

Tags: python, list, hash, reinforcement-learning

I want to use three lists as a index for a table in Python. To do so I decided to hash the lists to a int, because you can not use lists as an index.

The Problem is that the hashed vaule is a number like: -103692953590217654
This can not be used as an index as well.

How can I turn this high int into a smaller number, so that it is usabel for a index of a table?

I need this solution to fill a q-table for a reinforcement learning framework. My state is definded with three lists.

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Have you considered using tuples?

Comment: you should consider using tuples and dicts

Comment: Tuples are hashable because they are immutable. Also, why do you want to index stuff with a whole list?

Comment: How can I use tuples for this porblem? My State is definded by three 2D Lists. And I simply want to use these States as an index of my q-table.

Comment: I'm confused. How did you hash a list and get -103692953590217654? The entire reason that lists can't be used as indices to a dict is because they're unhashable.

Comment: I have this as my State: [array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]), array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])]

To use this as a dict I tried to hash this to a int: x = hash(str(state))

After this I want to use this as a index for my q-table, like: self.q_table[hash(str(action))][hash(str(state))]

The int that the hash function responds is too high to use as a index of a table like that.

Comment: What is a "q-table" and what kind of values can be its indices?

Comment: A q-table is just a table where you can get the Reward from a given State for a given Action. So my input are three matrices as a state and I want to use them as a dict key for the table. Do you see any solutions?

Answer (score 2):

Tuples are hashable, and sounds like you should be using them for your case.

As an arbitrary example:

```
a = (1,2)  
b = (3,4)  
q_learning_dict = {}  
q_learning_dict[(a, b)] = 0.1
```

To convert your lists to tuples, you can simply pass them to the `tuple()` function like `tuple([1,2,3])`.

**Warning:** Tuples are IMMUTABLE. This means that you cannot change their content after you initialize them (which is also what makes them hashable).

Hashing a list doesn't make sense because you can change the contents of the list or append/remove values to/from it, which would render your previous hash invalid.

Comment: I want to change the values inside of my lists.  I was searching for an opportunity to use my three state lists as a key for my q-table. Hashing them into a int was just my first idea, nut this leeds me to the next problem with the int.

Comment: If you change the values inside the lists, the hashes you calculate will not be valid, so that's not possible. @NicoHe

Comment: Do you have another idea to solve this problem? The hashing was just a try to use the lists as a dict for my q-table.